# How to track a PYPI project using google analytics?

Tags: python, google-analytics, pypi

I'd like to track my pypi project using google analytics. I was wondering where exactly I should embed the google analytics' code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) to send hits.
If you are able to send http request with something like the requests module:

```
pip install requests
```

You can use something close to the example below, with your own tracking id and parameters.

```
import requests

payload = {'v': '1',                # Version.
           'tid': 'UA-XXXXX-1',     # Tracking ID / Property ID.
           'cid': '123456',         # Anonymous Client ID.
           'dh': 'www.example.com', # Document hostname.
           'dp': 'home',            # Page.
           't': 'pageview'          # Hit Type.
          }

requests.post('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', payload)
```

Just ensure the code runs during any given event you wish to track.

Comment: Where can I find the client ID?

Comment: The client Id is simply a unique identifier. For analytics.js it is stored in the cookie and be accessed through the tracker.

ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});

For your use case perhaps you want use something like the mac address of the computer.

from uuid import getnode as get_mac
cid = get_mac()

Comment: If I wanted to track all the traffic to the project page, are you suggesting that I should have the above script running constantly?

Comment: No, Perhaps I miss understood your question originally. The solution I was providing was a means of programmatically tracking the use of a python application. But from your comment it sounds like you want to track the web traffic to the page your project hosted on pypi.python.org? If that is case the easiest method would be just to include the the standard Google Analytics snippet.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ 

I do not know if they allow you to include JavaScript on your project page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to include Google Analytics code for a project on PyPI. However, you can include it on the project's website (if any) and other pages related to the project, such as documentation.

Comment: Since pypi can issue http requests it is, however, possible to use the measurement protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to send data to Google Analytics.

Comment: How exactly? Can you provide a step by step example?

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff: By pypi, do you mean pip?